# Why is poetry only available from the .poetry\bin directory?

Tags: python-poetry

I installed poetry to windows using get-poetry.py. I cloned the entire poetry-master folder from the github to my desktop, unzipped it, then ran the install file. It asked me if I would like to modify something but responding both yes and no didn’t allow me to input any addiditonal information. The .poetry file ended up in my user directory. (Ex: C:\Users\CursedDog19\ .poetry)

I need poetry to install a package from GitHub for testing but my install of poetry only runs from one directory (\ .poetry\bin) Poetry claims to run from all directories.

Comment: the poetry docs include [an example](https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#add) of how to add a dependency with git as a source. Can you demonstrate in your question how that doesn't work in a way that anyone could reproduce the issue you're experiencing?

Comment: Sounds like `.poetry/bin` isn't in your `PATH`. How have you installed `poetry`? What shell are you using?

Comment: I updated my question with additional info. I hope this is helpful.